In Java how can I write a PKCS#8 PBES2 Encrypted Key?
I am trying to create an encrypted PKCS#8 Key in Java but fail at the PBES2  algorithm parameters step. I want to use SUN/SunJCE and not have to use BouncyCastle/IAIK JCEs.

can convert ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY -> PRIVATE KEY;
fail at PRIVATE KEY -> ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY - how do you get correct AlgorithmParameters for PBES2 ?

I have hit two bad alternatives:

get correct algorithm name PBES2 in AlgorithmParameters; but then cipher/kdf are not initialized in ASN.1
get all the ASN.1 fields correct, but SUN/SunJCE don't accept a long name PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256; I traced the code and it is looking for PBES2

Plain key:
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQguwofTpfqBCC6NPhF
WB5b6IfkD8C1mj2fdxyrYCCE/s+hRANCAAQLYKgHgOgGTWYDCaPO60XpdYXPYtao
nz1YtmZHooR5QOz22QM4Iwyrkky01qsDJbWaXjQDTxWDwm2nMQuiEp2M
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

PBES2 encrypted key (password: "something")
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
MIH0MF8GCSqGSIb3DQEFDTBSMDEGCSqGSIb3DQEFDDAkBBClpAgdFf+Ezj405avG
//ZgAgIIADAMBggqhkiG9w0CCQUAMB0GCWCGSAFlAwQBKgQQgic0LMiWWQ4c4ZaA
O6dMYwSBkBKZhUitcgjw3uKYWnWGDzSRHUgvgKLf73D85anZ1yMO71t/ZCX7bC29
cVECnVSgL8fvyp/JZG1HDMJzLPNnENsESipk4wFgKnIWh/vlxT5mNSY4nFO/3My4
gRzlY1XJ+AA4qflU8tb0HfMTM42dmH2+DALmMsJgplntqX/9svv7h7pfsVoMckQX
dr/OetPvsA==
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----


class Pbes2Test {

    @Test
    void canParseThisKey() {
        File file = new File("src/test/resources/key-encrypted.der");
        byte[] fileData = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);

        EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encInfo = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(fileData);
        assertEquals("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256", encInfo.getAlgName())

        // so KDF is PBKDF2 and cipher is AES-256-CBC
        byte[] cipherText = encInfo.getEncryptedData();

        // get: salt, iv, iterationCount
        AlgorithmParameters algParameters = encInfo.getAlgParameters();
        var paramSpec = algParameters.getParameterSpec(PBEParameterSpec.class);
        AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = paramSpec.getParameterSpec();

        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec("something".toCharArray(),
                paramSpec.getSalt(),
                paramSpec.getIterationCount(),
                32 * 8);

        SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        SecretKey myKey = skf.generateSecret(spec);

        byte[] myKeyData = myKey.getEncoded();
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(myKeyData, "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

        cipher.update(cipherText);
        cipher.doFinal();

        System.out.println("Profit!!");
    }

    @Test
    void cannnotCreateEncryptedPKCS8DER() throws Exception {
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec;
        PBEParameterSpec paramSpec;
        PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec;

        File file = new File("src/test/resources/key-plain.der");
        byte[] plaintext = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);

        byte[]  salt = new byte[16];
        byte[]  iv = new byte[16];
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        int iterationCount = 2048;

        random.nextBytes(salt);
        random.nextBytes(iv);

        ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        // ---- do cryptography
        pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec("something".toCharArray(),
                salt,
                iterationCount,
                32 * 8);

        SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        SecretKey myKey = skf.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

        byte[] myKeyData = myKey.getEncoded();
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(myKeyData, "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

        ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        buf.write(cipher.update(plaintext));
        buf.write(cipher.doFinal());
        buf.close();

        System.out.printf("Successfully created encryptedData!! size = %d\n", buf.size());

        // ---- ASN.1
        EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encryptedPrivateKey;
        File file2;

        // Take 1: this looks wrong; where is AES-256-CBC, PBKDF2 added to the AlgorithmParameters?
        AlgorithmParameters outputParameters = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("PBES2");
        paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount, ivSpec);
        outputParameters.init(paramSpec);

        // FAIL: Cipher AES-256-CBC, KDF PBKDF2 not initialized
        encryptedPrivateKey = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(outputParameters, buf.toByteArray());

        file2 = new File("test-output/TEST-key-encrypted.der");
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file2, encryptedPrivateKey.getEncoded());

        // Take 2: this almost works but has the wrong name!
        AlgorithmParameters outputParameters = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256");
        paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount, ivSpec);
        outputParameters.init(paramSpec);

        // FAIL: constructor only accepts "PBES2" and not "PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES"
        encryptedPrivateKey = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(outputParameters, buf.toByteArray());

        file2 = new File("test-output/TEST-key-encrypted.der");
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file2, encryptedPrivateKey.getEncoded());
    }

}

Take 1 exception, parts of ASN.1 not initialized:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "sun.security.util.ObjectIdentifier.encode(sun.security.util.DerOutputStream)" because "oid" is null
    at java.base/sun.security.util.DerOutputStream.putOID(DerOutputStream.java:317)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PBES2Parameters.engineGetEncoded(PBES2Parameters.java:378)
    at java.base/java.security.AlgorithmParameters.getEncoded(AlgorithmParameters.java:380)
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.<init>(AlgorithmId.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.get(AlgorithmId.java:480)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.<init>(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:191)
    at integration.keystore.OpenSSLTest.foStackExchage(OpenSSLTest.java:278)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)

        DerOutputStream encryptionScheme = new DerOutputStream();
        // algorithm is id-aes128-CBC or id-aes256-CBC
        encryptionScheme.putOID(cipherAlgo_OID);


Take 2 exception, bad algorithm name:
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: unrecognized algorithm name: PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.get(AlgorithmId.java:477)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.<init>(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:191)
    at integration.keystore.OpenSSLTest.foStackExchange(OpenSSLTest.java:278)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)


Notes:

IAIK has PBES2ParametersSpec: https://javadoc.sic.tech/iaik_jce/current/iaik/pkcs/pkcs5/PBES2ParameterSpec.html
BouncyCastle has PBES2Parameters: https://downloads.bouncycastle.org/java/docs/bcprov-jdk18on-javadoc/org/bouncycastle/asn1/pkcs/PBES2Parameters.html
possible issue with SUN/SunJCE - https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8289153


You can generate various types and level and chains withe JDK compiler "keytool".  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html

... this needs to be done programmatically so keytool is not an option

Ok - I found a workaround - create two AlgorithmParameters one with the correct name, and one with the correct body; then init the first one with the body from the 2nd one. Yes, this is really nasty...
Any better way?
/* right name, wrong body; don't init yet;
 * PBEParameterSpec does not have enough information to initialize this
 * object: cipher OID and kdf OID will be missing
 * https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8289153
 */
AlgorithmParameters realParams = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("PBES2");


/* wrong name, right body; do initialize
 * the SunJCE SPI initializes everything incl. cipher OID
 * kdf OID, but stores an incorrect String algorithm 
 */
AlgorithmParameters tempParams = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256");

PBEParameterSpec pbeSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount, ivSpec);
tempParams.init(pbeSpec);

/*... invasion of the body snatchers  ... initialize with the
correct body */

realParams.init(tempParams.getEncoded());

new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(realParams, encryptedData); // profit!!

